# QA for android in a small team

Tags: android, android-testing

I am planning to implement tests in my company for our android apps.

We have 2-3 apps, 3 developers, 1 QA.

I want to have a smooth plan for everyone to start learning how to write tests and use testing tools. Our QA can't code.

**Let me share the flow I came up with :**

1. Three amigos (Product owner, QA and dev) gather and lay down the specifications
2. Developers write the program using TDD (Test Driven Development). Along the way they make sure to handle tests cases written in specification with :

   a. Unit Tests (eg. a phone number starting with 08) using Junit

   b. Integration Tests (eg. Adding an "Phone" to the database also create a "Customer" entity) using Junit and Mockito

   c. and UI tests (eg. When clicking "Contacts" button, it displays "ContactsFragment) using Espresso.
3. In the meantime, QA already wrote the complete sheet of end to end tests and check it through once dev are done. I really want this phase to be as automated as possible.

**Now my questions are :**

1) What do you think about this plan ? (how do/would you do it ?)

2) For our QA, is there any tools out there that provides end to end tests automation without writing code ? I have only found MonkeyRunner so far.

Comment: I think you should post on the SE site, not SO: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Automated tests don't write itself by magic, no matter which tool you use. Some coding will be necessary, just the programming language used for this varies.

Comment: I moved it to SE. As for automated tests, dev would be writing it. But I wonder if QA can't use tools to automate UI testing without code for eg

Comment: Encourage the QA to look up for Espresso and also check Appium with Robot Framework example, if want to go without "coding".